# Opencv commands are needed to be called as root using 'sudo', otherwise shows error

Tags: 14.04, root, opencv

When I enter into my Opencv project directory and do the following command-

```
sudo cmake .
sudo make
```

it generates make files without any error and the program runs successfully.

But when I do

```
cmake .
```

it gives me this error-

"CMake Warning at /home/naman/opencv-2.4.9/cmake/OpenCVConfig.cmake:161 (message):
  Found OpenCV Windows Pack but it has not binaries compatible with your
  configuration.

You should manually point CMake variable OpenCV_DIR to your build of OpenCV
  library.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

```
/home/naman/opencv-2.4.9/cmake/OpenCVConfig.cmake
```

but it set OpenCV_FOUND to FALSE so package "OpenCV" is considered to be
  NOT FOUND.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!"

And it complies successfully in my friend's pc when done

```
cmake .
```

How to remove this error?

Comment: Never use `sudo` to run `cmake` (or other build configurators such as `./configure` scripts) under your home directory - it usually causes the generated files to become root-owned so that subsequent build attempts **without** `sudo` fail in mysterious ways. Start over (either `chown` everything back to your user, or - better - unpack a clean copy of the project) and see if you still get the error.

Comment: Yes I tried them already but it did not work.

Comment: Did you previously install OpenCV elsewhere (perhaps under `wine`)? Does your user's environment define any OpenCV related variables (`env | grep CV`)?

Comment: I initially installed OpenCV 2.4.9 version and it was working fine(not under wine).Then I tried to install 3.0 but failed to install it.Then these errors occured.

I also tried to found that that CMake variable 'OpenCV_DIR' but could not get it.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your OpenCV was installed as root, and hence its owner is root. Try running these commands in terminal:

1. Get to know yourself `whoami`
2. Locate OpenCV directory (`sudo` may be needed) `whereis opencv`
3. Go to OpenCV directory

   ```
   cd `whereis opencv`
   ```
4. Change ownership recursively to yourself

   ```
   sudo chown -R `whoami`
   ```

Comment: No it didn't work.

Comment: You did use output of `whoami`, not literally `[whoami]`, yes? If so, I cannot help.

Comment: Yes obviously I wrote my username there.But anyways,thanks for your help.